# Mocking location on android device

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I am trying to test my app which uses GPS location updates. I am try to make it work indoor when I can't get any GPS signal, by mocking device's location. I followed the tutorial [here](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/testing-with-mock-location-data-in-android/) but I when my app runs, it's still not picking up any location updates.

Can anyone spot what is wrong with my code?

```
        MockLocationProvider mock = new MockLocationProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this);
        mock.pushLocation(-12.34, 23.45);

        LocationManager locMgr;

        locMgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location Loc) {
        double lat = Loc.getLatitude();
        double lon = Loc.getLongitude();
        String l = "Longitude: " + lon + " Latitude: " + lat;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), l ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


public class MockLocationProvider {
        String providerName;
        Context ctx;

        public MockLocationProvider(String name, Context ctx) {
            this.providerName = name;
            this.ctx = ctx;

            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(
                    Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            lm.addTestProvider(providerName, false, false, false, false, false,
                    true, true, 0, 5);
            lm.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, true);
        }

        public void pushLocation(double lat, double lon) {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(
                    Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            Location mockLocation = new Location(providerName);
            mockLocation.setLatitude(lat);
            mockLocation.setLongitude(lon);
            mockLocation.setAltitude(0);
            mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(System.currentTimeMillis());
            mockLocation.setAccuracy(2);
            lm.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, mockLocation);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

While your code listens for location updates, you should mock the location at same time.

In your case, whenever you call pushLocation method then onLocationChanged method will be fired.

*listening for gps*

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location Loc) {
    double lat = Loc.getLatitude();
    double lon = Loc.getLongitude();
    String l = "Longitude: " + lon + " Latitude: " + lat;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), l ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

*to simulate it*

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public void loopMock(){
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // onLocationChanged method will be fired
            mock.pushLocation(-12.34, 23.45);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```